# Architecture for application with sockets

Tags: android, sockets

The concept of the application is simple: The user will interact with the interface, different messages will be sent to a remote server and the answer will show in the screen.

I have created a class called **MessageInterface** to deal with **AsyncTask** and the messages send/reception.

The data flow, since the user interacts with the interface, till he/she receive an answer, is this:

```
UI Element -> MessageInterface -> AsyncTask -> Android Socket -> Server

Server -> Android Socket -> AsyncTask -> MessageInterface -> ??
```

I have tried different solutions with **??**. Calling to different **MainActivty** methods depending of the message received, creating a **FragmentsInterface** called by the **MessageInterface** to deal with the appropriate fragment... but none of them satisfies me.

This is my first project using sockets in Android, I have deal with sockets in other platforms (python, C, C++/Qt) and never felt so frustrated

Any suggestion for the architecture I should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manuel, (I hope I got your question right)

The *Async* task has different methods as follows:

*onPreExecute()*: this run on the UI thread, you can touch any view of the main activity.

*doInBackGroud():* this runs in its own thread, you CANNOT touch the views of the main activity.

*onProgressUpdate()*: This method runs in the UI thread, so you may touch (update) any view of the main activity, like for example show the message that has been received.

*onPostExecute()*: this method runs in the UI thread, you may touch any view of the main activity, but this method executes only once, when the *doInbackGroud()* method finishes.

With this in mind, in the *doInbackGround()* method you may call, whenever you want, the *onProgressUpdate()* method to update a *TextView, Listview* or whatever view you use to display the received message. You may pass a string to the *onProgressUpdate* or any object you prefer.

On the other hand, you can use a *ConcurrentLinkedQueue* to add the messages (Strings or Objects) in the UI and poll them in the *doInBackGround* process to send them to the server.

if you need an example of this, let me know and I'll send it to you.

Saludos.

Comment: I was using AsyncTask in that way. But (if I am right) I do have to pass the caller object to AsyncTask and store it as an attribute, so I can use it in onPostExecute(). The problem with this approach is that any kind of Object can call this AsyncTask (Fragments or ActionItems). A different AsyncTask (depending of the caller object) is possible, but this solution will do a code duplication.

Comment: @Manuel, Well not exactly, why not pass, instead of an object, a callback method and let that method decides what to do with the message? Maybe I do not get the exact problem you have.

Comment: Gracias!, with the callback I do not need either the FragmentInterface or the MessageInterface. Now it looks much more coherent. The problem was an increasing complexity because I did not realise that the "callback" makes it much more simple.